# How to modify a stucture inside function

Tags: matlab

I have following stucture:

```
Struct = struct('x', 0, 'arr', [0, 0, 0]);
```

I wrote a function that modifies the Structure inplace:

```
function [ ] = changeStruct( Struct )
Struct.x = 123;
Struct.arr(2) = 1234;
end
```

Unfortunately, the function does not have any effect and the Structure remains unchanged!

```
changeStruct(Struct);
Struct.arr(2)   % this gives 0
Struct.x        % this also gives 0
```

How can I do that?

Of course I can return modified Structure, and update the original like this:

```
Struct = changeStruct(Struct)
```

But I would like to avoid copying it every time.

Comment: Are you familiar with how MATLAB passes variables to functions? By value. Not just structs, anything. You'd need `evalin` to counteract that, but I'd avoid that: let your function return the modified struct, and overwrite your original with that.

Comment: This would be terribly inefficient since my struct is huge and matlab would have to copy struct each time. Is there any other way of doing that?

Comment: As I said, calling `val=1234; evalin('base',['Struct.arr(2)=' num2str(val) ';'])` will work if your struct is called `Struct` in the base workspace, but `eval` is only a letter away from `evil`.

Comment: Depending on how complicated your `changeStruct()` is, a compromise might be to let `changeStruct()` compute the desired new values for certain fields, then return those to the caller and set them there.

Comment: Omg, matlab is so terrible. Thanks!

Comment: Passing by value has both pros and cons:) For instance, I've never had to deal with pointers in MATLAB;)

Comment: Why not make your struct a MATLAB object and define a method on the object which changes some of the objects properties. Make sure you subclass from handle.

Comment: Use Python. You won't regret it. EDIT: Oh you use it already :) Why do you poison yourself ?

Comment: It's not as bad as you make it out to be! I'm pretty sure (sorry I couldn't find a source for this claim) that if you make a function of the type `[x] = fun(x)` and call it like `y=fun(y)`, the matlab parser will not allocate two instances of the variable `y` if it is not needed.

Comment: @percusse Project at my University, we have to use it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put Struct in the output

```
function [ Struct  ] = changeStruct( Struct )
```